# NSFetchResultsController, populate new data into the table view

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to implement `UIRefreshControl` the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshController = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshController addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshController];
}

- (void)refresh:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Freshing");
    //populate new data into the table view
}
```

I am using `NSFetchResultsController`. So, how to populate new data into the table view?

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: your wc.. if you have any problem then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly simple. The `NSFetchedResultsController` is responsible for fetching the data for the table view, so:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If you still get "old" data, and you followed the Apple boiler plate code with lazy instantiation of the fetched results controller, you add this one line above:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
```

Rather than just setting this to nil, you could also just make the existing FRC perform its fetch request again (which is more efficient):

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

Comment: I am using UIRefreshController, I use these code to perform refresh:NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
    } but the endRefreshing is not called. how do i make sure i am not getting the old data?

Answer (score 0):

After getting data you have to reload your table

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```